# Issue with sticky footer not horizontally scrolling, and main content bunching up when window size collapsed

Tags: javascript, html, css

Marked as fixed!!!

I fixed myself the main_container issue by adjusting width of that and nav to 1280px instead of 1024.

I also fixed the footer scrolling by adding the jQuery/Javascript I wrote (below). It was my fault as I didn't realise you weren't able to link a .js file running locally without downloading file and placing in directory. So, I just added that code to the head instead and linked to the Javascript library from google...

---

Testing out some layouts for a new site and am having issues with my sticky footer not horizontally scrolling when I collapse my browser window size.  Its position is fixed, which I wish it to be.  Also, the .main_container bunches up when you resize the browser window too, and I'd like it fixed center to the page width.

Hope you can help.

HTML:

```
<head>
<title>MIX IT IN THE BOX</title>

<!-- normalize to clean up and standardize the browser default styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./_css/normalize.css">

<!-- Custom CSS --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./_css/styles.css">

<!-- Modernizr allows HTML5 elements to work in older browsers -->
<script src"./_js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src"./_js/scroll.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="nav_container">

<header class="navbar">
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Store</a></li>

    <li id="Logo"><a href=""><p>Logo</p></a></li>

    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
</header><!-- end navbar -->

</div> <!-- end nav_container -->

<div class="main_container">

<div class="content">

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting     industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br /><br />

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br /><br />

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br /><br />

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br /><br />

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br /><br />

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br /><br />

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>

</div>

</div> <!-- end main container -->

<div class="hidden"><p></p></div> <!-- blank space after content -->

<footer id="main_footer">

<div id="footer" class="container">

    <div>   

            <form class="form_footer">
                <h4>SIGN UP TO OUR NEWSLETTER HERE &rarr; <input type="email" placeholder="your@e-mail.com" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'your@e-mail.com'" /></h4> <input type="submit">
            <!-- end newsletter sign-up -->
            <br />
                <h4>MY ACCOUNT &rarr; <input type="login" placeholder="your@e-mail.com" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'your@e-mail.com'" /> <input type="password" placeholder="password" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'password'" /></h4> <input type="submit" value="Login"> <input type="submit" value="Register">
                <a href="" style="font-size: 11px; color: #B2B2B2;"><u>Forgot Your Login Details?</u></a>
                <!-- end login -->
            </form>

        <div class="social">

            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">Services</a>
            <a href="">Store</a>

            <a class="social_pic" href=""><img src="./_images/Social/fb.png"></a>
            <a class="social_pic" href=""><img src="./_images/Social//twitter.png"></a>
            <a class="social_pic" href=""><img src="./_images/Social//instagram.png"></a>
            <a class="social_pic" href=""><img src="./_images/Social//linkedin.png"></a>
            <a class="social_pic" href=""><img src="./_images/Social//email.png"></a>

            <a href="">Blog</a>
            <a href="">About</a>
            <a href="">Contact</a>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="copyright">
        <p>Copyright &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> MIX IT IN THE BOX.  All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>

</div> <!-- end footer container -->

</footer> <!-- end footer -->


</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
min-width: 100%;
}

body {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background: url('../_images/Background/wood 4.jpg') top no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 1440px 960px;
}

/* -- Header -- */

header nav {
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
}

header nav ul { 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
display: block;
line-height: 141px;
}

header nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px 10px;
}

header nav ul li a {
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}

header nav ul li#Logo a {
display: block;
width: 292px;
height: 141px;
background: url('../_images/Logo/logo.png') center center no-repeat;
}

header nav ul li#Logo a p {
opacity: 0;
}

/* -- Navigation Container -- */

.nav_container {
width: 1024px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px 24px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

/* -- Main Container -- */

.main_container {
color: black;
width: 1024px;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 10px 24px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

/* -- Footer -- */

#footer {
background-color: white;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
}

.copyright {
color: black;
opacity: 0.2;
padding-bottom: 2px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: -8px;
width: 1440px;
}

footer#main_footer div.container {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 40px;
}

.form_footer {
display: block;
margin-bottom: -12px;
}

div.social img {
width: 40px;
margin-top: 12px;
}

.social, a {
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
padding: 0px 10px;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
width: 1440px;
}

.social_pic {
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
top: 12px;
}

h4 {
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* -- blank spacing at bottom of main container -- */

div.hidden{
height: 170px;
width: 100px;
}

/* -- form styling -- */

form {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
width: 1440px;
}

/* -- center placeholder form text -- */

input {
text-align: center;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
text-align: center;

}

:-moz-placeholder {
text-align: center;

}


/* Force Elements to Self Clear its Children: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ */

.clearfix:after {
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
content: "";
clear: both;
height: 0;
}
* html .group             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .group { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

I read in a jsFiddle of possibly using javascript to allow the sticky footer to scroll horizontally, but couldn't get it to work...

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    console.log("scrolling");
$(window).scroll(function(){

        $('#footer').css('left', 0 - $(this).scrollLeft());
    });
    });
```

Ok, thanks in advance for any help, really need it as I'm a newbie just learning all this stuff.  Thank you!

Comment: Site with images etc can be downloaded here for offline testing - https://app.box.com/s/63tjb92xyi1jln9ulorcjqgv9kxgvcvh

Comment: I was just told that the javascript above is jQuery and note I'm missing an outside call to the library.  I added that jQuery library from Google, but it made no difference and i'm still stuck with issues presented.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have two problems:

1. `.main_container` doesn't scale down and stay centered as you resize the browser.
2. The content of `#footer` doesn't center and stays at its original position and width as you resize the browser, causing horizontal scrolling.

The problem lies in some of the things you've done to create this layout. If I were going to create this, it would look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <header class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Nav and stuff up here too.</p>
    </header>

    <main class="main">
        <p>Main content here.</h3>
    </main>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Footer stuff down here.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #333;
    padding: 20px;
}

.container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.header,
.main,
.footer {
    background: white;
    padding: 40px;
}

.main {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 150px; 
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .1 );
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, that's the layout and function you're going for. Here's a JSFiddle for a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/galengidman/x17wtj52/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Galen, really appreciated!  Fixed the main_container issue by adjusting width of that and nav to 1280px instead of 1024.  I'd prefer latter px size, but it works so I'm happy.

Fixed the footer scrolling by adding the jQuery/Javascript I wrote. It was my fault as I didn't realise you weren't able to link a .js file running locally.  So, I added that code to the head instead and linked to the Javascript library from google...

Comment: Ok, all good.  I just have 1 issue now with the footer not aligning center with Firefox and Chrome.

Please kindly download n replace index and css:

https://app.box.com/s/sbfut8rij1ll1qzkmbjoqdyjjhduf6op 

https://app.box.com/s/5rfits0g9gohg05ib1eue7inphacjuya

It has something to do with the width and position fixed I think not parsed by those browsers???

Just try making the browser window bigger and you'll see it doesn't extend full width and it's aligned left, not center.

Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.  Hope to fix.

:)

Comment: Also, I'm testing this on Safari 8.0.4 on my laptop, but just checked it out on Safari 6.2 on my desktop Mac and am not seeing any padding for the main_container... I suspect as my screen resolution is lower than the size and for using a 19" monitor.

I'd like it to be consistent between all browsers and backwards compatible,so would appreciate much help with that also... :)

Comment: 1 last thing for the eve, I think my widths for .nav_ and .main_ containers, .copyright and .form might be off for all this to work, for pushing the footer's size.  Not sure where I've gone wrong there?